# Create JSON string using standard functions using PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am using Oracle database ver 12.1.0.2. I need to create JSON string using standard PL/SQL functions. **Without using 3rd party libraries**. For an example,

```
declare
   json_text varchar2(20);
begin
   json_text.add_as_json("key","value");
end;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
declare
   json_text varchar2(20);
begin
   json_text := '{"key":"value"}';
end;
```

but that obviously gets tedious in real-world cases. Better use a lib for that, for example this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/

Comment: Surprisingly this seems to be as good as it gets.  There are several Oracle methods for *reading* JSON but there doesn't appear to be anything for *writing* JSON.